# Database Corruption Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wanted to check if there is anyway to make a MP to check is there are data corrupted databases on the instance.
Dose MP of database integrity is enough ?

Comment: Depends on what you consider *corrupted data* - in any case this question would be better suited for [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi, is this still open? Do you need any further hell?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look here `DBCC CHECKDB`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064%28v=sql.100%29.aspx   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258278(v=sql.80).aspx

Also you might check the list on the left of the page given with other DBCC commands (especially `CHECKCONSTRAINTS`). With `FREEPROCCACHE` you can force all objects to be recompiled - but regretfully not before the next time they are called.

It might be a workaround - if you need this - to get a list of all compileable objects with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` and call them with `SET FMTONLY` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/ms173839 deprecated but still usefull) or with `sp_describe_first_resultset` (see the links on the second page given). This would enforce their re-compilation immediately.

Comment: I think you meant `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064%28v=sql.100%29.aspx`

Comment: @TT, Yes, this was the one I wanted :-) Speed kills... I added yours, thx!